# Serving Django static files in OpenShift

Tags: django, openshift

According to the [March 2014 blog post](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/openshift-online-march-2014-release-blog), OpenShift now got rid of some directories like wsgi/, wsgi/static/, data/ and libs/.

Given I used wsgi/static for this purpose, how I am supposed to serve django static files from now on?

Comment: See this question on SF: [How to serve static files on OpenShift Python cartridge](http://serverfault.com/q/671274/104579)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [openshift.conf.erb](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-python/usr/versions/shared/etc/conf.d/openshift.conf.erb), it seems like it checks if you have a `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/static` directory and it keeps it working. I haven't verified that this works, but it looks like it should.

Comment: Yeah, it works as before, so I had to create the missing directory. I guess this will need some work to add support in a customizable way