# Static files on Openshift with Django

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404, openshift, wsgi

I can't found my static files like css, js and picture. I get 404 error page.

In my **settings django** I have

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/lib/openshift/*id*/app-root/repo/*project*/*app*' 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and my filesystem are

```
 - project
   - app
     - wsgi.py
     - static # I also tried to move this folder in wsgi folder
       - css
         - base.css
     - ...
```

I tried to move the **static folder** in **wsgi folder created before**.
I also tried to move **my static folder or wsgi folder in data** folder of openshift without success.

I follow few help posts from Stackoverflow without found my answer

- [Static files on OpenShift Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595223/static-files-on-openshift-django)
- [Serving Django static files in OpenShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660304/serving-django-static-files-in-openshift)

Can you help me to configure my static folder ?

Thanks

Comment: Can I write something in .htaccess ?

Comment: What is the apache configuration for static folder ? This location is fixed in apache ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **wsgi.py** I have to have

`sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR']))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' ] = 'project.settings.app'`

and in my **settings.py**

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.getenv('OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'), 'wsgi/static', )
STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

And the filesystem of my website

`repo
 project
  ...
 wsgi
  static
 wsgi.py`

Answer (score 0):

in your settings.py make sure you have:

```
import os
import sys

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files'),
                   )  # create static_files dir and place there your static  
                      # files to be collected, as static is the destination
                      # directory of your local and other Django 
                      # modules static files 

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', )
STATIC_URL = 'http://yourdomain.com/static/'
```

once done run

```
 ./manage.py collectstatic
```

make sure you have tree like

```
 yourproject+
            |
            +-yourproject
            |           | 
            |           +urls.py  
            |           |
            |           +settings.py
            |           |
            |           +wsgi.py
            |
            +manage.py
            |
            +static_files
            |
            +static
```

Comment: I tried your post @dmitryro but it does not solve my issue

Comment: Please update your wsgi.py and manage.py and see what specific error messages you're getting, if amy

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure your manage.py is modified to be:

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yourproject.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line  

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

and wsgi.py to be

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yourproject.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: My **wsgi.py is good**. I haven't to use `./manage.py collectstatic` if my static folder is already full ?

Comment: You HAVE to use it as the static is where files are TAKEN, not where they are initially placed. The philosophy of Django to collect files from all over the known places in your OS and place them into static.

Comment: STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]    # this is used by Django to check static files and set them in STATIC_ROOT

Comment: collectstatic makes sure your static files are up to date and are reachable by Django.

Comment: Thanks @dmitryro but even if I launch the command I can't reach my static files

Comment: Try specifying it explicitly as STATICFILES_DIRS = '/your_location_from_root/static'

Comment: I put the absolute path in STATICFILES_DIRS and STATIC_ROOT without success

Comment: I have to access to my static file by `http://yourdomain.com/static/...` ?